# using phpExcel type numeric % sign is not appearing in numeric cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

i am using following code to show percentage in excel sheet when i use following code it hides "**%**" percent sign from sheet it show 29 not 29% i want to make this numeric but want to show it with "%" sign

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
 ->setCellValueExplicit('A1', '29%', PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);
```

Comment: A string containing a % sign is NOT numeric.... setting explicitly to numeric will cast the value to a numeric, which means the % is dropped

Comment: yes exactly but i want both together now its working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 29);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(
        '0 "%"'
);
```